# Background thread brakes upcall from JavaScript to JavaFX

Tags: javascript, multithreading, javafx, webview

After migrating JRE version 1.8.0_66 to 1.8.0_111 I've encountered an issue with making upcall from JavaScript to JavaFX.

Long story short: while there is a running background thread, WebView/WebEngine refuses to make JS-to-Java calls.

I use WebView to render HTML content which is generated from a domain Data Model (DM). Content contains  elements with a handler assigned to it as follows:

```html
 <a href='#' onclick='explainHeadWord(this)'>some_word</a>
```

JS part looks like:

```js
function explainHeadWord(hwElement) {
    jsBridge.jsHandleQuery(hwElement.innerHTML);
}

function testBridge() {
    jsBridge.jsTest();
}
```

where `jsBridge` is an inner Java class of the Controller

```java
public class JSBridge {

    public void jsHandleQuery(String headWord) {
        log("jsBridge: jsHandleQuery: requested %s", headWord);
          handleQuery(headWord);
      }

      public void jsTest() {
        log("jsBridge: jsTest: test succeeded ");
      }
 }
```

which is injected as follows:

```java
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
          JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
          window.setMember("jsBridge", new JSBridge());
        //engine.executeScript("jsTest()");
        //engine.executeScript("explainHeadWord(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0])");
        //engine.executeScript("jsBridge.jsHandleQuery(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0])");
}
```

Besides the main DM I have an Index of cross-references which is `Map<String, Collection<String>>` built from DM, and a trigger method rebuilding that Index in the background each time DM changes. The first approach (which is worked fine on version 1.8.0_66) was based on ExecutorService:

```java
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private Future<Boolean> indexer = executor.submit(() -> false);

...
private void rebuildIndex() {   
    executor.submit(() -> {
        indexer.cancel(true);
        indexer = executor.submit(() -> {
              fullSearchIndex = getIndex();
              if (isIndexingAborted()) return false;
              return true;          
        });             
        try {
              if (indexer.get()) {
                  log("resetIndex: Done");
                updateTableView();
               }            
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        ...             
        }
      });
 }
```

As was expected, clicking on an anchor in a WebView resulted to a JS-call `jsBridge.jsHandleQuery(hwElement.innerHTML)` and eventually to `handleQuery(headWord)` method call implemented in Controller. But after migrating JRE to version 1.8.0_111 WebView stopped to respond to an anchor clicking.

I've investigated logs and found that injecting `jsBridge` was successful as well as executing test scripts commented in the code below line `window.setMember()`. Clicking on an `<a>` element led to nothing. But without running test scripts (commented) there were records appeared in the log:

```java
<record>
    <date>2017-01-09T02:00:47</date>
    <millis>1483920047169</millis>
    <sequence>160</sequence>
    <logger>com.sun.webkit.WebPage</logger>
    <level>FINE</level>
    <class>com.sun.webkit.WebPage</class>
    <method>fwkAddMessageToConsole</method>
    <thread>11</thread>
    <message>fwkAddMessageToConsole(): message = TypeError: jsBridge.jsHandleQuery is not a function. (In 'jsBridge.jsHandleQuery(hwElement.innerHTML)', 'jsBridge.jsHandleQuery' is undefined), lineNumber = 26, sourceId = jar:file:/.../jar.jar!/view.js</message>
</record>
```

And after a moment the background (indexing) thread was complete and a content in the WebView was reloaded clicking on `<a>` elements starts to respond again - `jsBridge.jsHandleQuery` was executed.
The indexing thread executes `getIndex()` method that traverses DM and returns collected into `Map` data from DM. There's niether any interaction with FX application thread nor WebView depends on Index. Substituting `fullSearchIndex = getMockIndex();`

```java
private Map<String, Collection<String>> getMockIndex() {
    try {           
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }        
    return Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

in background thread doesn't change `<a>`'s behavior.

Next step was to refactor background thread into FX style by utilizing 
`javafx.concurrent.Service` but the result is the same.

Will appreciate for pointing at what do I do wrong and how to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to instantiate Bridge outside of the listener, i.e.,

```
final JSBridge bridge = new JSBridge();
engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
      JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
      window.setMember("jsBridge", bridge);
    }
});
```

(Worked for me migrating from 1.8.0_91 to 1.8.0_121).